# Sympy : "The same variable should be used in all univariate expressions being plotted."

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to plot the V(\phi) as function of \phi, but this error prevents me. What I am doing wrong?

```
    from sympy import symbols
    from sympy.plotting import plot as symplot
    from sympy import varfrom sympy import plot_implicit, Eq

    V_phi, phi, lamb, mu = symbols(r'V \phi \lambda \mu')
    V_phi = mu*phi**2 + lamb*phi**4
    symplot(Eq(V_phi),(phi,-100,100))
```

The error:

```
    ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-26-a4e0c44827e2> in <module>
           ----> 1 symplot(Eq(V_phi),(phi,-100,100))

   ~/Anaconda3/envs/Py37/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   1351             if len(free) > 1:
   1352                 raise ValueError(
-> 1353                     'The same variable should be used in all '
   1354                     'univariate expressions being plotted.')
   1355     x = free.pop() if free else Symbol('x')

ValueError: The same variable should be used in all univariate expressions being plotted.
```

Comment: Maybe you can only plot if you substitute explicit values for mu and lambda? Otherwise, how does the system know what to plot?

Comment: For example `symplot(V_phi.subs(mu, 3).subs(lamb, 2), (phi, -100, 100))` seems to plot something.